# How to stop goroutine from client?

Tags: go, goroutine

I need to create a html page which has two buttons, one will start a goroutine, which has an infinite loop, and other button need to break the infinite loop. As from my readings I understood that a goroutine can't be killed from outside it. Is there anyway to implement this? My code is as follows:

```
command := c.GetString("command") // from client to determine which button is clicked
quit := make(chan bool)
switch command {
    case "start":    // Button to start goroutine
        go func() {
            i := 0
            for {
                select {
                    case <- quit:
                        return
                     default:
                         fmt.Println("i: ", i)
                         i++
                         time.Sleep(3000 * time.Millisecond)
                 }
             }
         }()
     case "stop":    // Button to stop goroutine
         quit <- true
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much the standard way to do it, yes, are you having any specific problems with it?

Comment: Is it allowed to press "start" button multiple times, ie there might be more than one goroutine running?

Comment: @ain No there won't be multiple goroutines...

Comment: @Jsor The stop is not working. Even after the stop button is pressed the loop is continuing..

Comment: Unrelated, it's just as easy to close quit (`close(quit)`) in your "stop" case as it is to send a message over it, and close won't block (though it _will_ panic if you try to do it more than once).  I typically use close because it can terminate more than one listening routine in a single operation, instead of having to send a message to each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already right about the design. An issue is that you are creating new channels each time you recieve a command. Which means there is no way to communicate with the previously started goroutine. You need to have a `quit` channel that stays in scope for between requests. Try something like below (untested):

```
func listenForCommand() {
    var quit chan bool

    for {
        // command receiver, should fire for each command received
        command := c.GetString("command")

        switch command {
        case "start":
            if quit != nil {
                continue
            }
            quit = make(chan bool)
            go func() {
                i := 0
                for {
                    select {
                    case <-quit:
                        return
                    default:
                        fmt.Println("i: ", i)
                        i++
                        time.Sleep(3000 * time.Millisecond)
                    }
                }
            }()
        case "stop":
            if quit == nil {
                continue
            }
            quit <- true
            close(quit)
            quit = nil
        }
    }
}
```

You can now call `listenForCommand()` to start listening for commands. This example presumes that there is another process populating `c` so `c.GetString("command")` returns a command if available, or blocks and waits for a command to arrive.

Comment: Can you please explain the comment **defined out of you command receivers loop/callback** ? I tested your code but stop is not working. May be I defined channel wrong again.

Comment: Edited above. Note that it's still an example. For above example to work properky, `c.GetString("command")` needs to act like a channel, as mentioned above.

Comment: Can't we break from the loop? I think in this code, the switch control is transferred to case "stop" from case "start", loop is still running.

Comment: How have you defined `c.GetString`? And the type `c`?

Comment: type c is the controller receiver and c.GetString is beego function.

Comment: If you're going to close `quit`, you don't actually need to send on it.   However, you also don't really want to set it to nil there, as the goroutine still needs to read the quit value from it (more critical if you use close, since it's async even on an unbuffered channel).  Better to set it to nil before the return inside the goroutine quit case.